# How to load annotation image after opened, not before

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have thousands of annotations on the map. Each annotation is a unique image. So, I don't want to load all the images on the map unless requested by the user.

My annotations have this property:

```
detailCalloutView: <Image source={{uri: data[i].img_url, cache: 'force-cache'}} style={styles.thumbnail} resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain}/>
```

How do I make the image only load when the annotation is opened? I don't want to shred through gigabytes of data by opening all annotations.

I think I need to do something with `onFocus` but I'm not quite sure how.

Comment: Create a small 1x1 image, and make that the src for each annotation. Then add a data attribute to each with the src of the real annotation. Once mouse over or clicked make JavaScript change the src to the data src.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

`detailCalloutView: <Image source={{uri: data[i].img_url, cache: 'force-cache'}} style={styles.thumbnail} resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain}/>`

To this

`detailCalloutView: <Image source="blanking.jpg" data-annotation={{uri: data[i].img_url, cache: 'force-cache'}}  style={styles.thumbnail} resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain}/>`

Then add an event listener to all the images in the map

```
var attr = this.getAttribute("data-annotation");
this.src = attr;
```

That's the main bit to add. And now even when closed it won't have to load again because the `src` will forever be the actual image. I'm not going to wrap the entire JavaScript for you but you should get the gist from this.

Comment: You can't add a listener to images in React Native, and when I add `onFocus: () => { ... }` to the annotation, there's no way to actually reference the specific image.

Comment: Additionally, `.src` is not valid in React Native from what I can tell.

Comment: I don't use react, I was simply adding my thoughts with native js. Since you are using the JavaScript tag

Comment: All other React Native questions were tagged with Javascript, so I followed suit.

Comment: Oh I'm sure they did. I don't use libraries so I can't suggest to you react anything, though you catch my drift on this. Use the small IMG and go from there with the event listener of choice. I'm sure you can get attributes some how.